# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1242 when i try to access the user search page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I try to access the search page from my web site I get this error, but only I access the search using a Mens profile, when I use another kind generates this error. How I can fix this, please?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 307

Backtrace:

File: /home4/trans4date/public_html/application/models/Mdl_common.php
Line: 86
Function: query

File: /home4/trans4date/public_html/application/controllers/Profiles.php
Line: 696
Function: allSelects

File: /home4/trans4date/public_html/index.php
Line: 308
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/trans4date/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: /home4/trans4date/public_html/application/models/Mdl_common.php
Line: 86
Function: query

File: /home4/trans4date/public_html/application/controllers/Profiles.php
Line: 696
Function: allSelects

File: /home4/trans4date/public_html/index.php
Line: 308
Function: require_once
```

A Database Error Occurred
    Error Number: 1242

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row

SELECT u.profileurlslug, u.fname, u.age, u.photo, u.transgendertype, u.transgendertype, u.user_type, u.orientations, u.relationship_status, u.country, u.country_code, u.city, u.totalphotos, u.active, u.User_ID, u.gender, (SELECT user_idfrom FROM dating_favourite WHERE user_idto=u.User_ID) as favourite FROM dating_users as u WHERE u.User_ID!='' AND u.gender='lb' AND u.active='confirm' AND u.User_ID!='9967' ORDER BY u.lastloggedin DESC limit 0, 20

Filename: models/Mdl_common.php

Line Number: 86
```

Here the code ( this happens when they tried show first the last logged users)

```
else{
    $sqlquery="SELECT u.profileurlslug, u.fname, u.age, u.photo, u.transgendertype, u.transgendertype, u.user_type, u.orientations, u.relationship_status, u.country, u.country_code, u.city, u.totalphotos, u.active, u.User_ID, u.gender, (SELECT user_idfrom FROM ".$this->tableprefix."favourite WHERE user_idto=u.User_ID) as favourite FROM ".$this->tableprefix."users as u WHERE u.User_ID!=''".$cnd." ORDER BY u.lastloggedin DESC $limitstr";
    $records=$this->mdl_common->allSelects($sqlquery);
    $data['records']=$records;
    $data['remaining']=$total-($limitstart+$totalrec);
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
```

When I back to this code, works fine again

```
$sqlquery="SELECT u.profileurlslug, u.fname, u.age, u.photo, u.transgendertype, u.transgendertype, u.user_type, u.orientations, u.relationship_status, u.country, u.country_code, u.city, u.totalphotos, u.active, u.User_ID, u.gender, (SELECT user_idfrom FROM ".$this->tableprefix."favourite WHERE user_idto=u.User_ID) as favourite FROM ".$this->tableprefix."users as u WHERE u.User_ID!=''".$cnd." $limitstr";
```

and the code is here

[code for the page profiles.php](https://codeshare.io/adgQkZ)

Comment: limit 1 in subquery or group concat result in subquery

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Sorry, now i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Subquery gets favorite column name returns more than one row. you can distinct keyword if the subquery returns the same value.